# Laravel - Upload Image 404

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller

I want to display an image on my website that i uploaded.

- In my database the image is store in `local/temp/` i don't know why.

I'm getting a 404 not found error when I want to access to the image

```
http://projet-site-e-commerceb2.test/storage/uploads/cL9pMFrZO92vliCKvlSgCq64TZOvnG3C2uzxgl6r.jpeg
```

- I did `php artisan storage:link` to put the storage folder to remain public.
- After i uploaded an image, i can see it in public/storage/uploads

HTML

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/' . $product->image)}}" style="height:200" class="card-img-top">
```

ProdcuctControllerController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $inputs = $request->except('_token');
        $product = new Product();
        $this->storeImage($product);
        foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
            $product->$key = $value;
        }

        $product->save();
        return redirect('admin/gamelist');
    }

    public function storeImage($product)
    {
        if (request()->has('image')){
            $product->update([
                'image' => request()->image->store('updloads', 'public'),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `public/` should not appear in urls, it should be the "DocumentRoot" of your server. Also, typo? `updloads` vs `uploads`

Comment: Okay , thanks i can see the image through the search bar. But that doesn't explain why my image are store in tmp file in my database :/